# Spring Boot with hibernate: Creating Composite Key and Many-to-many relations

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, orm, composite-key

I am trying to create a very simple Spring Boot application for storing sports data.

It has two entities: player and tournament. However, I want to store how each player placed in each tournament.

For this, I created the following ER Diagram. The junction table `PlayerPlacement_map` contains a relationship-attribute `placement` for storing how the players place in a tournament:
[image]

I have followed this guide on how to map the relationship between Players and Tournament, with Id from those two tables as a composite key in the junction table called `PlayerPlacementMap`: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

That has given me the following classes:

**Player.java** (**Tournament.java** follows a similar pattern - left out for brevity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;
                 

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "PlayerTournament_map",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Player_Id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Tournament_Id"))
    Set<Tournament> attendedTournaments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
    Set<PlayerPlacement> placements;

    //getters, constructors - left out for brevity
}
```

**PlayerPlacementKey.java** (making an embeddable composite key-class)

```
@Embeddable
public class PlayerPlacementKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "Player_Id")
    long playerId;

    @Column(name = "Tournament_Id")
    long tournamentId;

    //getters, setters, constructors, equals, hashcode - left out for brevity
}
```

**PlayerPlacement.java** (junction table)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PlayerPlacement_map")
public class PlayerPlacement {

    @EmbeddedId
    PlayerPlacementKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("PlayerId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "Player_Id")
    Player player;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("TournamentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "Tournament_Id")
    Tournament tournament;

    int placement;

    //constructors - left out for brevity
}
```

I have **repositories** for player, tournament and playerplacement. Player and tournament repositories are working fine on their own, and I am able to perform CRUD operations through a @RestController against a MSSQL database.

This is the **repository** for playerplacement:

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerPlacementRepository extends JpaRepository<PlayerPlacement, PlayerPlacementKey> 
{}
```

For the junction table, I have made a **PlayerPlacementController**:

```
@RestController
public class PlayerPlacementController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerPlacementRepository playerPlacementRepository;

    @PostMapping("/playerplacement")
    public PlayerPlacement addPlayerPlacement(@RequestBody PlayerPlacement playerPlacement) {
    return playerPlacementRepository.save(playerPlacement);
    }
}
```

**Finally, here comes the problem**: When I call the `/"playerplacement"` endpoint, I receive the following **error**:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.testproject.learning.model.PlayerPlacement
```

I think I have migrated the database just fine, but just to be safe, here is my **migration** for the junction table:

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerPlacement_map (

PlayerId Bigint NOT NULL,
TournamentId Bigint NOT NULL,
Placement int

CONSTRAINT PK_PlayerPlacement NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
(
    PlayerId,
    TournamentId
)

FOREIGN KEY (PlayerId) REFERENCES Players (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (TournamentId) REFERENCES Tournaments (Id)
);
```

I haven't been able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I appreciate all help and pointers that I receive - thanks in advance.

**EDIT:
Progress has been made with help of user Alex V., but I hit a new problem as of right now.**

I make the following **JSON** call:

```
{
    "player": 
    {
        "name":"John Winther"
    },
    "tournament": 
    {
        "name":"Spring Boot Cup 2020"
    },
    "placement":3
}
```

I don't set the `id` (composite key) myself - I guess it should be handled by something of the framework? Anyways, when I make this call in debug mode, I get the following **debug variables** set in the endpoint:

[image]

However, it results in the following **error**:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "o" is null`, which probably refers to my `equals`-method in `PlayerPlacementKey.java` (?):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof PlayerPlacementKey)) return false;
    PlayerPlacementKey that = (PlayerPlacementKey) o;
    return playerId == that.playerId &&
            tournamentId == that.tournamentId;
}
```

Hope anybody can push me in the right direction one more time.

Comment: You should add: `if(null == o) return false;` in `equals` method

Comment: Hey @alexvaluiskyi Thank you very much. I tried to add it to the first line of the `equals`-method, but unfortunately it returns the same error message. I  really have appreciated your help though, thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I understand you try to persist `PlayerPlacement` contains `Player` and `Tournament` are not persisted to the database? If so you have to add a proper cascade parameter for every relation: https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/#:~:text=MERGE%20%3A%20cascade%20type%20merge%20means,for%20the%20refresh()%20operation.

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi Again, Thank you very much Alex. I will take a thorough look at the documentation. I appreciate all the help youve given me

Answer (score 1):

Your entity has `playerId` field annotated as `@Column(name = "Player_Id")`, but database table contains `PlayerId` column instead of `Player_Id`. The same situation with `tournamentId`, `player`, `tournament` fields.

`@MapsId("TournamentId")` has to contain `@EmbededId` class field name `tournamentId` instead of `TournamentId`. It means the field is mapped by embeded id field `tournamentId`.

```
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("tournamentId")
@JoinColumn(name = "tournamentId")
Tournament tournament;
```

The same problem here `@MapsId("PlayerId")` .

Comment: Hello alex, sorry for late response, I was unavailble until now. For the first part of your answer, I understand it that in every column with name e.g. "tournament_id" or "player_id", I change it to match the database without underscore, e.g. "tournamentId"? For the second part of your question, do you mean that I should add @EmbeddedId("tournamentId") to the Tournament and Player fields in PlayerPlacement.java. In that case, I have four annotations on each. And also, it gives me an error when doing it. I was wondering if you have any documentation you can refer to or similar? Thanks.

Comment: Also, in Player.java I have defined a `@OneToMany` mapping named placements. Do I even need this, since I have already made a `@ManyToMany` map just above it?

Comment: I have edited the answer adding example in the second part.

Comment: Hey again Alex, thank you so much for getting back to me and adding more information. It pushed me in the right direction! Now I am able to properly call the endpoint and have some of the variables set. However, I am facing a new problem: I have added a description to the original post, starts at the bottom of the old post where I have added **EDIT** -tag. I hope you might be willing to take a look again. i really appreciate the help so far and hope to hear from you again.